# django template url tag optional parameter

Tags: django, url

Lets say I have these urlpatterns:

```
url(r'^area/(?P<area>[\w-]+)/?$', views.IndexView.as_view(), name="index"),
url(r'^$', views.IndexView.as_view(), name="index"),
```

How do I use template tag `url` to cope with the optional `area` parameter without `if else`

I tried the following:

```
{% url 'index' area=area %}
```

Problem is:

1. If area doesn't exist in template context, I get reverse not found.
2. If I set area to `None`, then url will become `/area/None`

Comment: I don't think you can do that. If `area` is supplied it tries to match the first url. If it is not, it matches the second. You cannot provide anything for `area` if you want to match the second.

Answer (score -2):

Replace your index urls with just one index url.

`url(r'^(?:area/(?P<area>[\w-]+))?$', views.IndexView.as_view(), name="index")`

I can test that from shell

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse, resolve
from django.template import Context, Template

Template("url1 is {% url 'index'  %}").render(Context())
Template("url2 is {% url 'index' area=1  %}").render(Context())
Template("url3 is {% url 'index' area='ab-12-cd' %}").render(Context())
```

Output

```
u'url1 is /'
u'url2 is /area/1'
u'url3 is /area/ab-12-cd'
```

Comment: doesn't seem to work, first because I still need to put in the url `area/` otherwise will get 404, second it will just make url to be `/area/None`

Comment: Default value for parameter `area` must be defined on your view.

Comment: but define to what? None?

Comment: @JamesLin you can use None. Check again one url should be enough for this.

Comment: I can't seem to get it to work, it's always rendering `/area/None` if area is default to `None`

Comment: for some reason I always got 404 if I don't specify `area/blah` in the url

Comment: @JamesLin: What do you get when you request `/` and `/area/123` ?